# Dynamic routing in Next.js 13 app directory throwing 404 Not Found error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I created a simple to-do app using Next.js 13 with TypeScript. I created an array of objects that contains an id string, and a name string. Then I map over the list and display the list names inside a Link element with the `href` set on `/listId/${list.listId}`.

[image]

// Parent page:

```js
 <div className='flex flex-col gap-2 py-2 pb-4'>
          { allLists.length > 0 && allLists.map((list: IList, index: number) => (
              <Link key={index} href={`/listId/${list.listId}`}
                className='border border-dashed border-gray-500 text-gray-800 px-3 py-1 rounded-lg'>
                <p>{ list.listName }</p>
              </Link>
          ))}
```

I need to navigate to the specific page and get the id on that page. But unfortunately, when prefetching and when navigating on the listId page, I get a 404 error...

I am not quite an expert in TypeScript, and this is my first time with a Next.js 13 app dir project.

// ListId page (server component):

```
interface IParams {
  listId: string
}

const ListNamePage: FC<IParams> = ({ listId }): ReactElement => {


  const router = useRouter();
  const { listName } = router.query;
  console.log(listName);
  
    
  return (
    <div>ListNamePage</div>
  )
}

export default ListNamePage
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making two mistakes. The first, causing the 404 error, is your `href`. As you defined your dynamic route folder, it should be `/839402...` and not `/listId/839402...`, like so:

```js
<Link
  key={index}
  href={`/${list.listId}`}
  className="border border-dashed border-gray-500 text-gray-800 px-3 py-1 rounded-lg"
>
  <p>{list.listName}</p>
</Link>
```

That's because, in the `pages` folder, the initial way of setting up routes, a file creates a route, but since Next.js `v13`, in the `app` directory, a route is created by a folder, and a `page.js` is used to render that route, as the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/defining-routes) shows it:

[image]

The second is in the way you are trying to get `listId` on the page; it should be as below. Notice I simplified the type:

```typescript
interface IProps {
  params: {
    listId: string;
  };
  searchParams: {};
}

const ListNamePage = ({ params }: IProps) => {
  console.log(params.listId);

  return <div>ListNamePage</div>;
};

export default ListNamePage;
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. So there is no need of the `useRouter` hook... However, I don't understand what `  searchParams: {};` is doing here..

Comment: Glad it did :) No no need for `useRouter` here. And `searchParams` is there because a dynamic page gets as a parameter an object which contains a `params` object, and a `searchParams` object, which holds URL paramters, you now the `?x=899`, while `params` holds the segment ids. And if you had URL parameters, you would add them in the type, like it's the case for `params`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create pages statically. From Next.js V13, you will need to use generateStaticParams() function. Here's the reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params